# Objactive C UISlider changing minimum track image only

Tags: objective-c, gradient, uislider

Im trying to setMinimumTrackImage of the slider using an image with CAGradientLayer, lets say using blue and red colors.

what happens is that the full track gets the gradient color, its starts with red, and sliding the Thumb to the right reveals the blue.
I want the color to start from red to blue up to the Thumb, ands "stretch" as the Thumb moves.

any ideas ? I though about setting the slider.maximumValue = slider...width 
and change the gradient image as I listen to the slider value change but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be successful trying to set the min track image.

Options are a completely custom slider...

or

Set the min track image to a clear image, add an imageView with the gradient image behind the slider, stretch the frame of the imageView to match the thumb movement.

Here's an example:

[image]

and the code (just a starting point... would be much better to wrap it into a subclass):

---

**SliderTestViewController.h**

```
//
//  SliderTestViewController.h
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 10/31/19.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface SliderTestViewController : UIViewController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**SliderTestViewController.m**

```
//
//  SliderTestViewController.m
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 10/31/19.
//

#import "SliderTestViewController.h"
#import "UIImage+Utils.h"

@interface SliderTestViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *theFakeSliderTrackImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISlider *theSlider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *imgWidthConstraint;

@end

@implementation SliderTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // instantiate a slider
    _theSlider = [UISlider new];

    // instantiate an image view to use as our custom / fake "left side" of the slider track
    _theFakeSliderTrackImageView = [UIImageView new];

    // we want the image to stretch
    _theFakeSliderTrackImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    // create a horizontal gradient image to use for our "left side" of the slider track
    // the image will be stretched... using a width of 128 seems reasonable
    UIImage *gradImg = [UIImage gradientImageWithSize:CGSizeMake(128.0, 4.0) startColor:[UIColor blueColor] endColor:[UIColor redColor] startPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) endPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0)];

    // set the gradient image to our image view
    _theFakeSliderTrackImageView.image = gradImg;

    // create a clear image to use for the slider's min track image
    UIImage *clearImg = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];

    // set min track image to clear image
    [_theSlider setMinimumTrackImage:clearImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // set max track image if desired
    //  [_theSlider setMaximumTrackImage:anImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    _theFakeSliderTrackImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _theSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:_theFakeSliderTrackImageView];
    [self.view addSubview:_theSlider];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[

        // constrain the slider centerY with 20-pts leading / trailing
        [_theSlider.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor],
        [_theSlider.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [_theSlider.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0],

        // constrain image view centerY to slider centerY
        [_theFakeSliderTrackImageView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_theSlider.centerYAnchor constant:0.0],
        // constrain image view leading to slider leading
        [_theFakeSliderTrackImageView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_theSlider.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
        // image view height to 5-pts (adjust as desired)
        [_theFakeSliderTrackImageView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:5.0],

    ]];

    // init imageView width constraint to 0.0
    _imgWidthConstraint = [_theFakeSliderTrackImageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:0.0];
    _imgWidthConstraint.active = YES;

    [_theSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self updateSliderGradientImage];
}

- (void)updateSliderGradientImage {
    // set "fake track" imageView width to origin.x of thumb rect (plus 2 for good measure)
    CGRect trackRect = [_theSlider trackRectForBounds:_theSlider.bounds];
    CGRect thumbRect = [_theSlider thumbRectForBounds:_theSlider.bounds trackRect:trackRect value:_theSlider.value];
    _imgWidthConstraint.constant = thumbRect.origin.x + 2;

}
- (void)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
    [self updateSliderGradientImage];
}

@end
```

---

**UIImage+Utils.h**

```
//
//  UIImage+Utils.h
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 10/31/19.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface UIImage (Utils)

+ (nullable UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size;
+ (nullable UIImage *)gradientImageWithSize:(CGSize)size startColor:(UIColor *)startColor endColor:(UIColor *)endColor startPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint endPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**UIImage+Utils.m**

```
//
//  UIImage+Utils.m
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 10/31/19.
//

#import "UIImage+Utils.h"

@implementation UIImage (Utils)

+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size {

    if (!color || size.height < 1 || size.width < 1)
        return nil;

    UIGraphicsImageRenderer *renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc] initWithSize:size];

    UIImage *image = [renderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext * _Nonnull context) {
        [color setFill];
        [context fillRect:renderer.format.bounds];
    }];

    return image;

}

+ (UIImage *)gradientImageWithSize:(CGSize)size startColor:(UIColor *)startColor endColor:(UIColor *)endColor startPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint endPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint {

    if (!startColor || !endColor)
        return nil;

    CFArrayRef colors = (__bridge CFArrayRef) [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                               (id)startColor.CGColor,
                                               (id)endColor.CGColor,
                                               nil];

    CGGradientRef g = CGGradientCreateWithColors(nil, colors, nil);

    startPoint.x *= size.width;
    startPoint.y *= size.height;
    endPoint.x *= size.width;
    endPoint.y *= size.height;

    UIGraphicsImageRenderer *renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc] initWithSize:size];

    UIImage *gradientImage = [renderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext * _Nonnull rendererContext) {
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(rendererContext.CGContext, g, startPoint, endPoint, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
    }];

    return gradientImage;

}

@end
```